# How to create a new environment for items with an image as bullet?

Tags: beamer

How to declare a fresh environment on which I can put items with an external local image, please?

Any brilliant suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an option defining a new overlay-aware environment `myitemize` which locally redefines the `itemize item` template to use an image; instead of `example-image-a` use your selected image and adjust the lengths according to your needs:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment<>{myitemize}
  {\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\includegraphics[width=20pt]{example-image-a}}%
    \begin{actionenv}#1%
    \begin{itemize}
  }
  {\end{itemize}\end{actionenv}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item First.
\item Second.
\end{itemize}

\begin{myitemize}
\item First.
\item Second.
\end{myitemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The solution above will change only the symbol used for the first level items; to change the symbols for all levels, change

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\includegraphics[width=20pt]{example-image-a}}%
```

to

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize items}{\includegraphics[width=20pt]{example-image-a}}%
```

And to get a different image for each level, you can do something like

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newenvironment<>{myitemize}
  {\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\includegraphics[width=20pt]{example-image-a}}%
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subitem}{\includegraphics[width=15pt]{example-image-b}}%
    \setbeamertemplate{itemize subsubitem}{\includegraphics[width=10pt]{example-image-c}}%
    \begin{actionenv}#1%
    \begin{itemize}
  }
  {\end{itemize}\end{actionenv}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item First.
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
    \begin{itemize}
    \item First.
    \item Second.
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\item Second.
\end{itemize}

\begin{myitemize}
\item First.
  \begin{myitemize}
  \item First.
  \item Second.
    \begin{myitemize}
    \item First.
    \item Second.
    \end{myitemize}
  \end{myitemize}
\item Second.
\end{myitemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]